# How to group the sorting of a file?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort delimited files with a `Time stamp | level | sensor name | measurement value` structure so that all data associated with the sensor having the smallest time stamp would first be listed in increasing timestamp, then all the data associated with the sensor having the second smallest time stamp would be listed in increasing timestamp, etc…

Here’s an example of delimited file to be sorted :

```
20140102073500|1|sensor5|0.188|  
20140102073502|1|sensor2|0.193|  
20140102073600|2|sensor5|0.577|  
20140102073603|2|sensor2|0.585|  
20140102073700|3|sensor5|1.207|  
20140102073702|3|sensor2|1.183|
```

Here what I want :

```
20140102073500|1|sensor5|0.188|  
20140102073600|2|sensor5|0.577|  
20140102073700|3|sensor5|1.207|  
20140102073502|1|sensor2|0.193|  
20140102073603|2|sensor2|0.585|  
20140102073702|3|sensor2|1.183|
```

(note that I cannot sort by "sensor name / time stamp" because the sensor with the smallest time stamp changes from one file to the other...)

Here the coding I’m trying to work from (which only sort in ascending time stamp) :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Sort8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Test\\test.txt"))) {
            map = new TreeMap<>();
            String line;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    map.put(getField(line),line);
                    System.out.println(getField(line));                                     
            }
                    System.out.println(map.values()); 
        }
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Test\\test_sorted.txt")) {
            for(String val : map.values()){
              //      System.out.println(val);   
                    writer.write(val) ; 
                    writer.write("\r\n");   
            }   
        }
    }
     private static String getField(String line) {   
               return ((line.split("\\|")[1])+(line.split("\\|")[3]));         
     }
}
```

I'm new to Java so thank in advance for the help you can provide !

Comment: Use comparator, provide one in the arguments of new TreeMap<>();

Answer (score 0):

Put a comparator in the construction of your tree map.

```
    map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            String[] a1 = s1.split("|");
            String[] a2 = s2.split("|");
            // First compare sensor
            int sensor1 = Integer.parseInt(a1[2].replace("sensor", ""));
            int sensor2 = Integer.parseInt(a2[2].replace("sensor", ""));
            if(sensor1 != sensor2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(sensor1).compareTo(sensor2);
            }
            // Second compare timestamp
            long time1 = Long.parseLong(a1[0]);
            long time2 = Long.parseLong(a2[0]);
            return Long.valueOf(time1).compareTo(time2);
        }

    });
```